# Как подключиться к mysql базу данных через окружение настроенное vagrant

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, phpstorm, vagrant

Всем привет. Недавно начал заниматься backend и настраивать свое окружение. Настроил через vagrant (https://habr.com/ru/post/416359/) вот ссылка кому надо. Сейчас понял что к базе данных я имею доступ только при включенном Live Server, когда я подключаюсь к ней через phpstorm, он пишет что соединение произошло, а на сайте пишется Access denied for user 'mysql'@'localhost' (using password: YES). Кто уже сталкивался с таким, подскажите новичку пожалуйста

Comment: "на сайте" надо использовать те же параметры подключения, что и "через phpstorm"

Comment: @Ипатьев, если ты про пароль с логином, то что в phpstrom, что на сайте они идентичные

Comment: если бы были идентичные, то тогда бы ошибки не было. надо еще раз проверить все настройки. и все свои предположения, вроде "пишет что соединилось", "могу только если включил" и так далее. Никакого особенного сакрального решения для проблемы "как указать такие же параметры подключения к бд" не существует. Их надо просто указать

Comment: вы через шторм к какой БД вообще подключаетесь? Той которая в "Live Server" или к той, которая в контейнере?

Comment: @Ипатьев, я через шторм подключаюсь к БД которая в Live Server

Comment: А какой смысл с ней соединяться?

Comment: @Ипатьев, не очень понял что вы имеете в виду. Смысл к ней подсоединяться чтобы брать оттуда данные

Comment: но вы же себе поставили виртуалку с БД. Вы определитесь сначала, с какой БД хотите работать. той которая в "Live server" или той, которая в виртуалке.

Comment: @Ипатьев, до меня дошло. Спасибо большой за помощь!

Comment: @Ипатьев, я только вашу фразу не очень понял, как работать с БД которая в виртуалке, где её создать?

Comment: Я не знаю. никогда не сталкивался с вагрантом. судя по всему, статья не такая замечательная. Наверное надо поискать другую.